# Calendar Assignment

Tags: c++

First, let me address everyone by saying hello! This is my first time using this resource (...and probably not my last). Having said that, I'll try to explain my issue to the best of my ability. Here goes nothin'...

The assignment is to populate a 2D array using c++ given a month, year, and day of week for the calendar to start on. I've managed to get as far as gathering the amount of days (for the month) from the user, the year, and the start date, but I cannot wrap my head around how to populate the 2D array correctly without getting a read access error, as shown:

"Exception thrown at 0x01288B7F in Calendar.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00290000."

A sample of output can be seen here:

"Enter month: February

Enter year: 2016

Enter day of week: Saturday
A
B
D
E
F
G
Sun Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat
H

8 9 10 11 12 13 14 H

15 16 17 18 19 20 21 H

22 16 17 18 19 20 21 H

22 23 24 25 26 27 28 H

29 23 24 25 26 27 28 H

29 23 24 25 26 7 1409053844 H

0 0 2130567168 7 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 H

-858993460 3930364 -858993460 -858993460 3930360 -858993460 -858993460 H

3930364 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 H"

As you can see, it gets wonky toward the end, even before it begins spitting garbage.

The function in question is here:

```
void displayMonth(int leapRes, int start)
{
    int month[6][7] = { 0, 0 };

    cout << "F" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = month[i][j]; j < leapRes; j++)
        {
            month[i][j] = j;
        }
    }

    cout << "G" << endl;

    cout << "Sun Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = month[i][start]; i < leapRes; j++)
        {
             if (j % 7 == 0) 
            {
                cout << "H" << endl;
                cout << "\n" << month[i][j] << " ";
            }
            else
                cout << month[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I can offer further explanation to any part of the code I've provided.

Again, don't be too rough on me. I've elsewhere for possible clues on how to best navigate this assignment with little luck.

EDIT:

I've since made some changes to the function code, and while it's populating the array with the correct amount of days, it's neither starting the array at the correct position or aligning to a grid format.

```
void displayMonth(int numDays, int start)
{
const int ROW = 6;
const int COL = 7;
int month[ROW][COL] = { 0, 0 };
int k = 1;

cout << "F" << endl;
//trying to populate the 2D array
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
    {
        month[i][j] = k;
        k++;
        //things like this are just bench checking
        cout << "this is position " << j << " in the array: " << month[i][j] 
<< endl;
        system("pause");
        //again, bench checking
        cout << "1" << endl;
        if (k >= numDays)
            break;
    }
}

cout << "G" << endl;

cout << "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat" << endl;
//attempting to print said array
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
    {
        if (month[i][j] <= 0)
        {
            //cout << "2" << endl;
            cout << "---";
        }
        else
        {
            //cout << "3" << endl;
            cout << setw(3) << month[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This: `for (int j = month[i][j]; j < leapRes; j++)` cannot possibly work - what do you expect `j` to be?

Comment: When I change j to 0, or the start date, the loop stops iterating after it begins a new line, and just repeats the previous values.

Comment: Also this: `for (int j = month[i][start]; i < leapRes; j++)` creates and endless loop (as you never increment `i` inside it)

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that! I was going a bit crazy trying to figure out why my code was functioning like that.

Comment: @UnholySheep: Almost; `i` is incremented fine by a surrounding loop, but the condition should be `j < leapRes`.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I don't follow. Both inner for loops have j < leapRes as the condition.

Comment: @GerredDeptula: No, they don't. I think maybe you need to change your font, or pick better variable names. Or visit your optician :)

Comment: @JacoboCórdova: Huh? What is `k`?

Comment: @JacoboCórdova: Your answer doesn't "explain" anything at all; it just dumps code. Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is one place where `ctime` and the `struct tm`, would come in handy.  It would also help to wrap this up in a class(Month).

To fill the array properly you need 2 pieces of data, the weekday of the first day and the total number of days.  For the first `tm` contains a field for that(`tm_wday`).  For the second that can easily be calculated by subtracting the year day('tm_yday') of the first day of the following month with that of the first day of this month.  This has the advantage of automatically allowing for leap years.

Another thing to keep in mind when declaring the array. A month can use up parts of 6 weeks in the calendar.

Since we'll need two tm objects a helper function to create and populate the structs would be helpful.

Since most people are more used to thinking of months as names but `tm` uses an index, a `map<string,int>` would allow the constructor to take a month name and efficiently convert it to an index, as well as allow the class to store the name to print it out later.

The class could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::map;
using std::ostream;
using std::setw;
class Month
{
    static const int MAX_WEEK_DAYS = 7;
    static const int MAX_WEEKS = 6;
    map<string,int> months =
    {
        {"January",0},
        {"February",1},
        {"March",2},
        {"April",3},
        {"May",4},
        {"June",5},
        {"July",6},
        {"Auguat",7},
        {"September",8},
        {"October",9},
        {"November",10},
        {"December",11}
    };
    string _name = "";
    int _days = 0;
    int _weeks[MAX_WEEKS][MAX_WEEK_DAYS];
    int _year = 0;
    void InitNewDate( int year , int month , int day,tm& date )
    {
        time_t rawTime;
        time( &rawTime );
        tm* tempDate = localtime(&rawTime);
        tempDate->tm_year = year - 1900;
        tempDate->tm_mon = month;
        tempDate->tm_mday = day;
        rawTime = mktime( tempDate );
        tempDate = localtime( &rawTime );
        date = *tempDate;
    }
public:
    Month(int year, string name)
    {
        _year = year;
        tm newDate;
        InitNewDate( year , months[name] , 1,newDate );
        tm tempDate;
        if ( months[name] == 12 )
        {
            InitNewDate( year + 1 , 0 , 1,tempDate );
        }
        else
        {
            InitNewDate( year , months[name] + 1 , 1,tempDate );
        }
        _days = tempDate.tm_yday - newDate.tm_yday;
        _name = name;
        int day = 1;
        for ( int i = newDate.tm_wday; i < 7; i++,day++ )
        {
            _weeks[0][i] = day;
        }
        for ( int week = 1; week < MAX_WEEKS; week++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < MAX_WEEK_DAYS && day <= _days; j++ , day++ )
            {
                _weeks[week][j] = day;
            }
        }

    }
    void PrintMonth( ostream& out )
    {
        out << _name << ", " << _year << '\n';
        out << "Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n";
        for ( int week = 0; week < MAX_WEEKS; week++ )
        {
            for ( int day = 0; day < MAX_WEEK_DAYS; day++ )
            {
                if ( _weeks[week][day] <= 0 )
                {
                    out << "--- ";
                }
                else
                {
                    out << setw( 3 ) << _weeks[week][day] << ' ';
                }
            }
            out << '\n';
        }
    }
};
```

The constructor will initialize all the variables including the 2D array(`Month m( 2016 , "February" );`).
The `PrintMonth` function will print a formatted display(`m.PrintMonth(cout);`).

The output for February, 2016:

```
February, 2016
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
---   1   2   3   4   5   6
  7   8   9  10  11  12  13
 14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 21  22  23  24  25  26  27
 28  29 --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but your code is beyond the scope of the class I'm in.